# Почему не работает метод replace на объекте Series

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_apps["Price"] = df_apps["Price"].replace('$', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

В столбце Price цены формата $1.49, пытаюсь преобразовать их в числовой формат, но получаю ошибку:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$1.49'

В чем может быть причина того что replace не отрабатывает?

Comment: Проблема в том, что символ `$` надо либо экранировать в регулярном выражении, либо не использовать регулярку вообще.

Comment: Да, непонятно, зачем тут регулярки включены

Comment: @CrazyElf а как можно без регулярок убрать лишние символы? Буду признателен, если подскажете более оптимальное решение

Comment: @Kleso Да можно просто сделать `regex=False` и `$` будет восприниматься как обычный символ и успешно заменится. Вы в курсе вообще что такое регулярные выражения? )

Comment: @CrazyElf Только сейчас дошло) Копипастнул с другого фрагмента кода, где использовал регулярки и забыл, что они опциональны. Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое за комментарии, действительно нужно было просто экранировать символ $

```
df_apps["Price"] = df_apps["Price"].replace('\$', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```